# How do I set the Accept-CH:sec-ch-ua-platform-version,sec-ch-ua-full-version in Tomcat server level?

Tags: java, tomcat

As this is my first time configuring client hints, I am having a hard time getting the exact configuration in Tomcat server. Could you please assist me with this issue if you can? below hints have to configure in server side

```
 Accept-CH: sec-ch-ua-platform-version,sec-ch-ua-full-version,sec-ch-ua-full-version-list,sec-ch-ua-model,sec-ch-ua-arch,sec-ch-ua-bitness, sec-ch-ua-wow64
```